# Matrix or Cross Tab report with single field for both Column and Row group

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, crystal-reports, report, crosstab

I am trying to create a report of Matrix but I am not sure it is possible to achieve a matrix in SSRS or Crystal Report.

Table
    Subject     Student#
    English     10000
    English     10001
    English     10002
    Math        10001
    Math        10002
    Math        10003
    Math        10004
    Science     10000
    Science     10001
    Science     10007

I like to create a matrix report as below. It will show student counts in both subjects.
     ----------           English     Math    Science
     English     -- 3    ----------       2 -----       2
     Math__      --  2   ----------        4 -----       1
     Science     --2     ----------      1  -----      3

But both Crystal report and SSRS show only numbers in the meeting cells of the same subject. For example, 3 for English 4 for Math 3 for Science. all the rest cells show 0.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it is a best way to achieve but I found an answer myself.

In Crystal, I added a view as View1. I added the same view as view2. All links between the two were cleared. It means the two tables are no joined.
 A formula was created.
@BothSubjectStudentID
  if View1.StudentID = View2.StudentID then
    1
 else
    0

View1.Subject were added to the columns in a Cross Tab .
View2.Subject were added to the rows in the cross tab.
the formula 'BothSubjectStudentID' was added to summarized Fields:. with Sum().

It took a bit time and returned results I am looking for.